# Access violation writing location unity windows phone 10

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-phone

When I try to test my application on windows phone 10 (lumia 650 1 GB Ram), visual studio 2015 comunity give me this exception:

> Unhandled exception at 0x61EF232B (UnityPlayer.dll) in MyApplication.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00100FB6.

How can I solve that?

Comment: Did you get to camera problem solved?

Comment: Really I don't know, I want to know where is the problem or what caused that.

Comment: Sounds like a memory problem to me. Why not create a simple Project and then try to run it on your phone. If it does, open that old project up and start disabling scripts one by one. You will likely find out what's causing. Since I have no access to your project, I can't tell what's going on. Back up your project before doing this.